# What happens to the textureGrad function (samplerShadow and compare) if the calculated partial derivative is multiplied by a number greater than 1

Tags: glsl, vulkan

as vulkan spec said :If the image view has a depth/stencil format, the depth component is selected by the aspectMask, and the operation is an OpImage*Dref* instruction, a depth comparison is performed. The result is 1.0 if the comparison evaluates to true, and 0.0 otherwise. This value replaces the depth component D.

When my sampler opens compare and uses sampler1D (or 2D) Shadow for depth sampling, if the textureGrad parameter is dFdx and dFdy, the textureGrad function returns 0.0 and 1.0. However, when dFdx and dFdy are multiplied by a number greater than 1, the textureGrad function returns the value between 0.0 and 1.0。why?

Comment: Smells like an implementation bug for a compare sampler. Which GPU?